# Reuse a HRD migrated application's old identifier

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application hosted on GAE identifier foo.appspot.com. I recently migrated this app to bar.appspot.com. Now, can I use the application identifier foo.appspot.com to host a totally different application.

APP1 (Master/Slave) --> foo.appspot.com 
 APP1 (HRD) --> bar.appspot.com 
 Now foo.appspot.com internally redirects to bar.appspot.com. Can I deploy a totally new application, APP2 on foo.appspot.com, whereas APP1 will be directly accessed from bar.appspot.com? (as below)

APP1 (HRD) --> bar.appspot.com 
APP2 (HRD) --> foo.appspot.com

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you still own it and have not deleted it just deploy your application to it's new home simply by changing the value for `application:`given in the `app.yaml` and redeploying it. You may want to delete the items in the datastore, clean up memcache first however. You can delete all datastore items in bulk from the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul. I deployed a new application on the old identifier, but the old identifier is still pointing to the old application only.  Let me rephrase my problem-- APP1 (Master/Slave) --> foo.appspot.com, APP1 (HRD) --> bar.appspot.com. Now foo.appspot.com internally redirects to bar.appspot.com. Now can I deploy a totally new application, APP2 on foo.appspot.com, whereas APP1 will be directly accessed from bar.appspot.com?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now. But I'm afraid I've no answer. I'll upvote your question.